# Locking down multiple sites in Sitecore

Tags: url-rewriting, sitecore

I have two sites running under one Sitecore 6 installation. The home nodes of the sites are as such:

```
/sitecore/content/Home
/sitecore/content/Careers
```

Assuming the primary site is at `domain.com`, the careers site can be accessed at `careers.domain.com`.

My problem is that, by prefixing the uri with `/sitecore/content/`, any sitecore item can be accessed by either (sub)domain. For example, I can get to:

`http://domain.com/sitecore/content/careers.aspx` (should be under `careers.domain.com`)
`http://careers.domain.com/sitecore/content/home/destinations.aspx` (should be under `domain.com`).

I know I can redirect these urls (using IIS7 Redirects or ISAPIRewrite) but is there any way to 'lock' Sitecore down to only serve items under the configured home node for that domain?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure without testing it but you could try putting each site it its own security domain and denying access to each other. In the `<sites/>` node there is a `domain="extranet"` attribute, create a new security domain and set the Careers site to use it.

You can create new security domains using the domain manager in the Sitecore desktop.